# Any idea on how WolframAlpha did this sum?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, trigonometric-series, geometric-series

So I've been trying to work out this sum for quite a while:
[image: Image of sum]

WolframAlpha unfortunately won't supply step by step proofs for this for some reason...

As for how i tried to prove this:
I looked at sin((2n-1)*a) as the imaginary part of cis((2n-1)*a), which is a geometric series (a_n = a_1*q^(n-1), where a_1 = cis(a) and q=cis(2a)), therefore its sum from n=1 to n=k should be:
[image: Formula for partial sum of geometric series]

Meaning the sum is:[image: sum]

(Note: I used De Moivre's Theorem to put the n power inside the cis)

But no matter how i tried continuing from here i always arrived at a huge trigonometric expression which i did not see how it (the imaginary part) could become what WolframAlpha is saying it is...

Any directions/solutions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Using images in this way is discouraged. You might get a better response using LaTeX

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/42969

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MartinR thanks! I managed to prove it using the formula in the link you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

(i) $$\sin a+ \sin 3a+...+\sin ((2k-1)a)$$ $$=\sin a+\sin 2a+...+\sin 2ka-(\sin  2a+\sin 4a+...+\sin 2ka)$$ (ii) Use forward differences $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^b \Delta f(k)=f(b+1)-f(1)$ $$\text{(iii)   }\sin k \theta=(\Delta (\cos ((k-1/2)\theta)) )/(-2 \sin (\theta/2))$$ ()iv  Put in (i) $\theta=a$ and $\theta =2a$ and subtract.